# RadioButtonList - display only radio button typed in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I need to make radiobuttonlist to be filterable as we typed in textbox. Means If I type `M` then `Music` & `Movie` radio should be shown. This I want to achieve with JS or jquery to avoid postback. I have not good idea of either of them.

Please suggest me such kind of things which is already done to refer.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="Radio1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <asp:ListItem value="1">Music</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="2">Sports</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="3">Cooking</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="4">Travelling</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="5">Moview</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem value="6">Cricket</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: How about `.filter` ?

Comment: @Rayon didn't get you

Comment: He mean this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava I don't know js well. I need one example

Comment: @StupidRomeo, Can you share browser rendered HTML ?

Comment: @Rayon you really need browser render HTMlL because I didn't tried anything yet. I need help to do this thing

Comment: What method you will apply if you want to try with `.filter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RadioButtonList` will create the following markup, so you could `each` over the labels and use regex to `toggle` the row:-

```js
$('#TextBox1').keyup(function() {

  var text = $(this).val();
  var regex = new RegExp(text, 'ig');

  $('#Radio1 label').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggle(regex.test(this.innerText));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input name="TextBox1" type="text" id="TextBox1">

<br/>
<br/>

<table id="Radio1" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="Radio1_0" type="radio" name="Radio1" value="1">
        <label for="Radio1_0">Music</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="Radio1_1" type="radio" name="Radio1" value="2">
        <label for="Radio1_1">Sports</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="Radio1_2" type="radio" name="Radio1" value="3">
        <label for="Radio1_2">Cooking</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="Radio1_3" type="radio" name="Radio1" value="4">
        <label for="Radio1_3">Travelling</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="Radio1_4" type="radio" name="Radio1" value="5">
        <label for="Radio1_4">Moview</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="Radio1_5" type="radio" name="Radio1" value="6">
        <label for="Radio1_5">Cricket</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```